# Multiple ajax call with different url in one function

Tags: ajax

In the 1st ajax call I am storing output of a service in a variable. That is working fine. Then I have to use that variable as input in another service, different url. Is it possible to write in same ajax function?
And if possible, then how to do that?

Comment: Why can't? You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using promises. In this case you'd have to return a promise from the function.

Comment: Can you explain it with example?

Comment: Have a look at this, [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining). If that doesn't work for you, maybe accept a callback [callback example](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbuecheler/Y9Ca8/)