# How to call same ajax function on multiple pages with different url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hı gusy!
I am trying to drop ajax post function to one and use it on whole site with different url on each page.

This is my original function and how it works :

```
<button type="button"class="submit">send</button>

$(document).ready(function (){
   $('.submit').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ActionPage.php',
            data:form.serialize(),
            success:function(vardata){
             var json = JSON.parse(vardata);
              if(json.status == 101){
               alert(json.msg);
                window.location.replace("/");
                } else {
                 alert(json.msg);
                 console.log(json.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Exp: I have multiple forms in some pages, so I need to use `$(this).closest('form');` to post each form.

**This is what I want to do**, original function will be in scripts and included in page :

```
  function ajaxLoader(url) {
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        "url" : url, 
        data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(vardata){
            var json = JSON.parse(vardata);
            if(json.status == 101){
              alert(json.msg);
              window.location.replace("/");
            } else {
              alert(json.msg);
              console.log(json.msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And on the page I want to call it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.submit').on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      ajaxLoader("ActionPage.php", true);
  });
});
```

I getting undefined message on all cases when I click send button, when I move `$(this).closest("form");` to second function then I get undefined form error.

I have searched on site there are similar question but none of them has usefull answer. example : [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37049628/19168006)

Comment: I only see ```<button type="button"class="submit">send</button>``` but no form tags.

Comment: _"And on the page I want to call it like this"_ - but there is a _static_ URL value in this - so what is the point of this whole question then? It thought exactly that part, the URL, was what you wanted to make "dynamic"?

Comment: @JonathanRomer yes didnt include form, just showed how it works.

Comment: Why are you passing `true` to your ajaxLoader function?

Comment: Thats why you get  ```undefined```. But there are more problems, check comments above.

Comment: Is your server actually returning a valid object?

Comment: @CBroe As I said just wanted to show how it works, that is why didnt include all form. just button. first function is the working function now on the site, the second one is how I tried, On each page I have to send different url to ajax.

Comment: There is no reason why `this` should point to your button in the second attempt - you are simply calling `ajaxLoader`, there is no connection whatsoever to the event any more at this point. Either store the element the event occurred upon into a variable in a scope that is also reachable from within `ajaxLoader`, or pass it to that function as an additional parameter.

Comment: @JonathanRommer clear explanition for you, I have a form in my page but its very long so I didnt include it in here, just showed how it works with button click. the problem is: it doesnt post form values to php side.

Comment: Basic example of how `this` works. The scope of it depends on how the functions are called.

Comment: @CBroe **There is no reason why this**,  what if I have multiple forms in same page ?

Comment: I just told you how to handle this within the very same comment you quoted from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `this` is scoped is based on the context of how it is called. You can change what this is with call/apply/bind. Basic example below.

```js
function ajaxLoader(url) {
  console.log(this, url)
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  console.log(form[0]);
}


$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.submit').on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      ajaxLoader.call(this, "ActionPage.php");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="foo">
  <button class="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is unclear how it would not post values. It should correctly reference the form. My guess is you did something different.

Comment: my bad sorry I played arround and moved `closest("form");` to call function corrected now

Comment: This is a great example to showcase the scope of "this". But I dont think this is a great solution for OPs specific problem. And using it might introduce a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).closest("form");` does not resolve to the closest form element of the clicked button when inside your function `ajaxLoader'. Do a 'console.log( this )' in that function.

You can either inject the form directly into your function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.submit').on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      let form = $(this).closest("form");
      ajaxLoader("ActionPage.php", form);
  });
});

function ajaxLoader(url, form) {
  ...
}
```

Or you could use the action attribute of your form and hook to the submit event of the form directly:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  const $form = $(this);
  const url = $form.attr('action');
  const data = $form.serialize();
  const method = $form.attr('method');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="actionpage.php" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Form example with submit is the best way to tackle this.